# Python: Store multiple dataframe in list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, store

I have a loop that read Excel sheets in a document. I want to store them all in a list:

```
  DF_list= list()

  for sheet in sheets:
     df= pd.read_excel(...)
     DF_list = DF_list.append(df)
```

If I type:

```
[df df df df]
```

it works.

Sorry I have a Matlab background and not very used to Python, but I like it.
Thanks.

Comment: DataFrame is an important class in pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html . You should name your objects something else like df / mydf etc.

Comment: Before attempting to write any code _please read the Python documentation_. In your case, you should read the docs of `list`. Or just run `help([].append)` from the interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will use parameter `sheet_name=None`:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel(..., sheet_name=None)
```

it will return a dictionary of Dataframes:

```
sheet_name : string, int, mixed list of strings/ints, or None, default 0

    Strings are used for sheet names, Integers are used in zero-indexed
    sheet positions.

    Lists of strings/integers are used to request multiple sheets.

    Specify None to get all sheets.

    str|int -> DataFrame is returned.
    list|None -> Dict of DataFrames is returned, with keys representing
    sheets.

    Available Cases

    * Defaults to 0 -> 1st sheet as a DataFrame
    * 1 -> 2nd sheet as a DataFrame
    * "Sheet1" -> 1st sheet as a DataFrame
    * [0,1,"Sheet5"] -> 1st, 2nd & 5th sheet as a dictionary of DataFrames
    * None -> All sheets as a dictionary of DataFrames
```

Answer (score 26):

`.append()` modifies a list and returns `None`.
You override `DF_list` with `None` in your first loop and the append will fail in the second loop.

Therefore:

```
DF_list = list()

for sheet in sheets:
    DF_list.append(pd.read_excel(...))
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
DF_list = [pd.read_excel(...) for sheet in sheets]
```

Comment: To be fair, he also gives an explanaition why the code did not work. Which is pretty usefull for a beginner.

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
DF_list= list()

for sheet in sheets:

   df = pd.read_excel(...)

   DF_list.append(df)
```

or for more compact python, something like this would probably do

```
DF_list=[pd.read_excel(...) for sheet in sheets]
```

Answer (score 3):

Complete solution is as follows:

```
# (0) Variable containing location of excel file containing many sheets
excelfile_wt_many_sheets = 'C:\this\is\my\location\and\filename.xlsx'

# (1) Initiate empty list to hold all sheet specific dataframes
df_list= []

# (2) create unicode object 'sheets' to hold all sheet names in the excel file
df = pd.ExcelFile(excelfile_wt_many_sheets)
sheets = df.sheet_names

# (3) Iterate over the (2) to read in every sheet in the excel into a dataframe 
#     and append that dataframe into (1)
for sheet in sheets:
    df = pd.read_excel(excelfile_wt_many_sheets, sheet)
    df_list.append(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's no need to define new list to store bunch of dataframes. The pandas.ExcelFile function applied on excel file with multiple sheets returns ExcelFile object which is a collection that can catch hold bunch of dataframes together. Hope the below code helps.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.ExcelFile('C:\read_excel_file_with_multiple_sheets.xlsx')

sheet_names_list = df.sheet_names

for sheet in sheet_names_list:
   df_to_print = df.parse(sheet_name=sheet)
   print(df_to_print)
```